# Is this the proper way to initialize null references in Scala?

Tags: scala, null

Let's say I have a `MyObject` instance which is not initialized:

```
var a:MyObject = null
```

is this the proper way to initialize it to null?

Comment: I think this gets an error if `a` is later assigned something.  Which is why I think this is a valid question:  in the old days an object can be null, but now this option is no longer available and we're forced to use "option" explicitly, adding to bulky code.

Comment: @YanKingYin No, this code correctly makes a variable that can be assigned to with real instances of `MyObject`. When trying to write this code, it's easy to make the mistake of writing `var a = null`, which declares the variable `a` of type `Null`, which is uninstantiable. Using `var a:MyObject = null` declares `a` with type `MyObject`, allowing it to hold references to instances of `MyType` later. Options are safer than using nulls directly, but they are optional.

Comment: Not according to IntelliJ.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

### Alternatives

Use `null` as a last resort. As already mentioned, `Option` replaces most usages of null. If you using `null` to implement deferred initialisation of a field with some expensive calculation, you should use a `lazy val`.

### Canonical initialisation to null

That said, Scala does support `null`. I personally use it in combination with Spring Dependency Injection.

Your code is perfectly valid. However, I suggest that you use `var t: T = _` to initialize `t` to it's default value. If `T` is a primitive, you get the default specific to the type. Otherwise you get `null`.

Not only is this more concise, but it is necessary when you don't know in advance what `T` will be:

```
scala> class A[T] { var t: T = _ }
defined class A

scala> new A[String].t
res0: String = null

scala> new A[Object].t            
res1: java.lang.Object = null

scala> new A[Int].t   
res2: Int = 0

scala> new A[Byte].t
res3: Byte = 0

scala> new A[Boolean].t
res4: Boolean = false

scala> new A[Any].t   
res5: Any = null
```

### Advanced

Using `var t: T= null` is a compile error if T is unbounded:

```
scala> class A[T] { var t: T = null }
<console>:5: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Null(null)
 required: T
       class A[T] { var t: T = null }
```

You can add an implicit parameter as evidence that `T` is nullable -- a subtype of `AnyRef` not a subtype of `NotNull` This isn't fully [baked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335496/how-does-the-notnull-trait-work-in-2-8-and-does-anyone-actually-use-it), even in Scala 2.8, so just consider it a curiousity for now.

```
scala> class A[T](implicit ev: Null <:< T) { var t: T = null }           
defined class A
```

Comment: What's that <:< thing there?

Comment: Very helpful!  But why does it NOT suffice to put an upper bound of AnyRef on T, i.e. `class A[ T <: AnyRef ] { var t:T = null }` ?

Comment: Scala has an experimental trait, `NotNull`. If we have `class C extends NotNull`, `null` is not a subtype of `C`. This feature was turned off by default in Scala 2.8, as it isn't fully baked. But it is still around enough to mean you have to write `class A[T >: Null] { var t: T = null }` rather than `class A[T <: AnyRef] { var t: T = null }`

Comment: How to achieve initializing an Int to null, as I want to store the value null in database instead of default 0

Comment: @DimitrisAndreou The answer can be found [elsewhere on the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427345/what-do-and-mean-in-scala-2-8-and-where-are-they-documented)

Comment: write `null` instead of `_` is more concise, this probably is the worst reason to use something. `_` in scala could mean dozens of different thing. `null` does mean no value. Save 3 characters have a headache instead.

Answer (score 32):

The canonical answer is **don't use null**. Instead, use an option type:

```
var a = None : Option[MyObject]
```

When you want to set it:

```
a = Some(foo)
```

And when you want to read from it, test for None:

```
a match {
  case None => Console.println("not here")
  case Some(value) => Console.println("got: "+value)
}
```

Comment: As an aside, the canonical way to handle `Option` variables is **not** to use pattern matching, but to use collection/monad operations such as `map`, `getOrElse`, `flatMap`, `foreach`, `toList`, `filter` etc. For the example you gave, pattern matching seems to makes sense because you're taking distinct actions in each case, but in the majority of real scenarios the `None`s can be coerced out without being explicitly referenced.

Answer (score 9):

As David and retronym have already mentioned, it's a good idea to use `Option` in most cases, as `Option` makes it more obvious that you have to handle a no-result situation.  However, returning `Some(x)` requires an object creation, and calling `.get` or `.getOrElse` can be more expensive than an if-statement.  Thus, in high-performance code, using `Option` is not always the best strategy (especially in collection-lookup code, where you may look up a value very many times and do not want correspondingly many object creations).  Then again, if you're doing something like returning the text of an entire web page (which might not exist), there's no reason *not* to use Option.

Also, just to add to retronym's point on generics with `null`, you can do this in a fully-baked way if you really mean it should be `null`:

```
class A[T >: Null] { var t: T = null }
```

and this works in 2.7 and 2.8.  It's a little less general than the `<:<` method, because it doesn't obey `NotNull` AFAIK, but it otherwise does exactly what you'd hope it would do.

Comment: That seems incredibly and unreasonably complicated.

Comment: @pyrony - Compared to what?  Here, I simplified it a little.

Answer (score -1):

I came across this question since scalastyle told me to not use null when initialising an object within my test with `null`.

My solution without changing any type that satisfied scalastyle:

```
var a: MyObject = (None: Option[MyObject]).orNull
```

Comment: small tweak:
`var a: MyObject = Option.empty[MyObject].orNull`