# problem with implicit ambiguity between my method and conforms in Predef

Tags: scala

The following code, which is taken from Apocalisp's excellent blog series: 
[Type level programming in scala](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/type-level-programming-in-scala/) , and modified for an implicit parsing scenario. However, this does not compile, with the following message:

```
error: ambiguous implicit values:
both method hParseNil in object HApplyOps of type => (com.mystuff.bigdata.commons.collections.hlist.HNil) => com.mystuff.bigdata.commons.collections.hlist.HNil
and method conforms in object Predef of type [A]<:<[A,A]
match expected type (com.mystuff.bigdata.commons.collections.hlist.HNil) => com.amadesa.bigdata.commons.collections.hlist.HNil
val l = hparse[HNil,HNil](HNil)
```

Can someone please explain why this happens, and if it's fixable?

```
sealed trait HList

final case class HCons[H, T <: HList](head: H, tail: T) extends HList {
  def :+:[T](v: T) = HCons(v, this)
}

sealed class HNil extends HList {
  def :+:[T](v: T) = HCons(v, this)
}

object HNil extends HNil

// aliases for building HList types and for pattern matching
object HList {
  type :+:[H, T <: HList] = HCons[H, T]
  val :+: = HCons

}

object HApplyOps
{
  import HList.:+:



  implicit def hParseNil: HNil => HNil = _ => HNil

  implicit def hParseCons[InH,OutH,TIn <:HList,TOut<:HList](implicit parse:InH=>OutH,parseTail:TIn=>TOut): (InH :+: TIn) => (OutH :+: TOut) =
    in => HCons(parse(in.head),parseTail(in.tail))

  def hparse[In <: HList, Out <: HList](in:In)(implicit parse: In => Out):Out = in

}


object PG {

  import HList._


  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    import HApplyOps._

    val l = hparse[HNil,HNil](HNil)

  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although i can't tell you exactly the purpose of `Predef.conforms`, i can tell you the ambiguity error seems correct (unfortunately). In the comment in the source it even says that `<:<` was introduced because of ambiguity problems of `Function1` (says `Function2` but i guess that is a mistake). But since `<:<` is a subclass of `Function1` it can be passed in whenever `Function1` is expected, so in your case its possible to pass in `<:<` to hparse.

Now the `implicit def conforms[A]: A <:< A` has the effect (from what i understand) that whenever a method expects a type `A => A`, it is sufficient to have an implicit value of `A` in scope.

In your case the `implicit def hParseNil: HNil => HNil` has the same priority as `conforms` and thus both could be equally applied.

I see two possible solutions:

- just remove the `hParseNil`, i think your code still works.
- shadow the `Predef`'s `conforms` by naming yours the same:

  `implicit def conforms: HNil => HNil = _ => new HNil`

Comment: `conforms` (along with `tpEquals` and `conformsOrViewsAs`) provides the implicits required for Scala's [generalized type constraints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427345/what-do-and-mean-in-scala-2-8-and-where-are-they-documented).

Comment: You can also pass explicitly your actual choice to disambiguate. 
`hparse[HNil, HNil](HNil)(parse = MyParsingChoice )`
However, it kind of defeats the purpose of playing implicits here. When the problem comes from e.g. a third party library that you don't have control over, it may come in handy. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace the function literal `hParseNil` to a normal function.

`implicit def hParseNil(a:HNil): HNil = HNil`

instead of

`implicit def hParseNil: HNil => HNil = _ => HNil`