# How can I learn more about Scala's type relationships?

Tags: scala

This is surely a stupid question, but I'm stumped.  I've now read Odersky's book, and all the tutorials I can get my hands on, and I can't seem to find anything which explains some of the more obscure Scala type relationships.  For example, what is `=:=`? It's referenced [here](http://www.chuusai.com/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/), but doesn't even seem to be in the Scala language reference. Is there some reference material which explains this, which I'm missing?

Comment: Specifically for `=:=` and related operators, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427345/what-do-and-mean-in-scala-2-8-and-where-are-they-documented.

Comment: bookmark [1st ed Staircase book](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/) from artima.com, the index is great for symbolic "operators" which are really (mostly) methods/functions:

Comment: Alexey: Ah!  Thank you!  Very helpful... and Wow! that's weird!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a "normal" operator, albeit one that is somewhat obscure (and one that I have never used or heard about before ;-). The `=:=` operator is defined in the [magical] [Predef object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef%24).

See section 12.5: The Predef Object in the [SLS](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf):

> The Predef object deﬁnes standard functions and type aliases for Scala programs. *It [Predef] is always implicitly imported, so that all its deﬁned members are available without qualiﬁcation.*

(The SLS does not mention `=:=` or a few others; many are "implementation details".)

Happy coding.

Comment: Pedantry: `=:=` is not an operator; it's a class

Comment: @Luigi Plinge I tried to work out *how* it was applied, but failed miserably. A step by step "guide" of how such stuff in Predef even works would be nice! (Know of any? :-)

Answer (score 0):

The [Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.Predef%24%24%24eq%24colon%24eq) says:

> An instance of A =:= B witnesses that the types A and B are equal.

I did not have any trouble finding it, nor do I have any trouble understanding it (though knowing beforehand biases me in this). To improve it, I'd like to know what do you have a problem with: finding it, understanding it, or both?

Comment: I didn't realize it might be in the Scala API -- nor that it was a *class*!  I'd assumed it was a built-in type relationship of some sort, and thus was expecting in the language definition itself.  (It also doesn't help that Google can't easily search on such strings.)