# What does <:< mean in Scala?

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do <:<, <%<, and =:= mean in Scala 2.8, and where are they documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427345/what-do-and-mean-in-scala-2-8-and-where-are-they-documented)

e.g. in this example, from scala-arm 1.0:

```
def toTraversable[B](implicit ev: R <:< TraversableOnce[B]): Traversable[B] = 
  new ManagedTraversable[B,R] {
    val resource = self
    override protected def internalForeach[U](resource: R, g : B => U) : Unit = 
      ev(resource).foreach(g) 
  }
```

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf

Comment: For two thousand other duplicates, see [here](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%3C%3A%3C).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<:<` (and similar strange looking constructs) are defined in Predef.scala (source at [scala-lang.org](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/%3C:%3C.html)), which is probably the best resource for working out what they are.

In general, classes like that can be used to provide further bounds on the type parameters within the scope of a particular method.

The `<:<` in particular is used to **require** that `R` is a **subtype** of `TraversableOnce[B]`.

The description from documentation is:

> An instance of `A <:< B` witnesses that `A` is a subtype of `B`. Requiring
> an implicit argument of the type `A <:< B` encodes the generalized
> constraint `A <: B`.
>
> To constrain any abstract type `T` that's in scope in a method's
> argument list (not just the method's own type parameters) simply add
> an implicit argument of type `T <:< U`, where `U` is the required upper
> bound; or for lower-bounds, use: `L <:< T`, where `L` is the required
> lower bound.