# Type equality in Scala

Tags: scala

Here is a little snippet of code:

```
class Foo[A] {
  def foo[B](param: SomeClass[B]) {
  //
  }
}
```

Now, inside `foo`, how do I:
1) verify if B is the same type as A?
2) verify if B is a subtype of A?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need implicit type evidences, `<:<` for subtype check and `=:=` for same type check. See the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427345/what-do-and-mean-in-scala-2-8-and-where-are-they-documented).

Comment: Do I have to implement these implicits by myself in case A and B are classes defined by me?

Comment: @Sergey No, just append an extra (implicit ev: B <:< A) argument list to the method. Or (implicit ev: B =:= A) for equality.

Answer (score 7):

As a side note, generalized type constraints aren't actually necessary:

```
class Foo[A] {
  def foo_subParam[B <: A](param: SomeClass[B]) {...}
  def foo_supParam[B >: A](param: SomeClass[B]) {...}
  def foo_eqParam[B >: A <: A](param: SomeClass[B]) {...}
  def foo_subMyType[Dummy >: MyType <: A] {...}
  def foo_supMyType[Dummy >: A <: MyType] {...}
  def foo_eqMyType[Dummy1 >: MyType <: A, Dummy2 >: A <: MyType] {...}
}
```

In fact, I prefer this way, because it both slightly improves type inference and guarantees that no extraneous runtime data is used.

Comment: Hi @Ptharien's Flame, I've just seen your answer, and it seems interesting. Could you please explain it a little bit? Where does MyType comes from and how do you use the foo_eqMyType method? Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: @FrancisToth It’s just a placeholder name.  I could have used `Bar` or `Baz` just as easily.  In the example, `MyType` is meant to be some type that’s not a type parameter, but instead comes from elsewhere.  As for usage of the method, you just call it!  Type inference and type checking will take care of the rest automatically.

Answer (score 6):

> 1) verify if B is the same type as A?

```
class Foo[A] {
  def foo(param: SomeClass[A]) = ???
}

// or

class Foo[A] {
  def foo[B](param: SomeClass[B])(implicit ev: A =:= B) = ???
}
```

> 2) verify if B is a subtype of A?

```
class Foo[A] {
  def foo[B <: A](param: SomeClass[B]) = ???
}

// or

class Foo[A] {
  def foo[B](param: SomeClass[B])(implicit ev: B <:< A) = ???
}
```

---

In your case, you do not *need* [generalized type constraints](http://debasishg.blogspot.in/2010/08/using-generalized-type-constraints-how.html) (i.e. `=:=`, `<:<`). They're required when you need to add a constraint on the type parameter that is defined elsewhere, not on the method.

e.g. To ensure `A` is a `String`:

```
class Foo[A] {
  def regularMethod = ???
  def stringSpecificMethod(implicit ev: A =:= String) = ???
}
```

Here you cannot enforce the type constraint without a generalized type constraint.