# Get type class from generic in scala

Tags: scala, generics

I want to get actual type class from Generic type.

When I try this

I get class `scala.runtime.Nothing` only.

```
import scala.reflect._

class Car {

}

object Car extends Model[Car] {

}

trait Model[T] {

  def something[T:ClassTag]():Unit = {
    println(classTag[T].runtimeClass)
  }

}

Car.something() // <- scala.runtime.Nothing$
```

Comment: The two `T`s are different. Try: `Car.something[String]()` for example.

Answer (score 3):

You might want something like the following:
The `T=:=U` would [unify the two types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450949/type-equality-in-scala) and the `:ClassTag` would just create a `ClassTag` for it.

Edit: the correct, but still too complicated form:

```
trait Model[T] {
  def something[U](implicit ev: T =:= U, tag: ClassTag[U]): Unit = {
    println(tag.runtimeClass)
  }
```

In general, I would also use https://stackoverflow.com/a/27666845/1502148 (when I am not sleepy :) ).

Comment: This is 1) not a legal syntax; 2) more complicated than required if you fix the syntax to `def something[U](implicit ev: T =:= U, tag: ClassTag[U])`.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Model[T:ClassTag] {

  def something():Unit = {
    println(classTag[T].runtimeClass)
  }

}
```

I solved by modifying Model trait to class and provide ClassTag to Generic.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow creating a `Model` without `ClassTag` and only require `ClassTag` for some methods, you can do

```
trait Model[T] {
  def something(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]):Unit = ...
}
```

Obviously this applies to e.g. `Numeric`, `Ordering`, etc. constraints as well.