# How to restrict a method only to being used with a specific type?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a case class below

```
case class SomeCaseClass[M] private (
  value: String
)
```

and in another file, I have the following trait and object.

```
trait SomeTrait[A] {
  def get(oldId: String): A
   :
}

object SomeObject {
  private[this] def init[A](): SomeTrait[A] = new SomeTrait[A] {
    def get(oldId: String): A = id(oldId)
     :
  }

  val aaa: SomeTrait[String] = init[String]()
  val bbb: SomeTrait[SomeCaseClass[String]] = init[SomeCaseClass[String]]()
}
```

How should I modify the code so that restrict the init method only to being used with SomeCaseClass[_] type and not with any types like String as above?

Ideally with some modification to the code, the line `val aaa: SomeTrait[String] = init[String]()` should cause compilation error.

Answer (score 6):

This is what I came up with:

```
case class SomeCaseClass[M] private (
  value: String
) 

trait SomeTrait[A] {
  def get(oldId: String): A
}

private[this] def init[A <: SomeCaseClass[_]](): SomeTrait[A] = new SomeTrait[A] {
  def get(oldId: String): A = ???
}

val aaa: SomeTrait[String] = init[String]() // Will fail
val bbb: SomeTrait[SomeCaseClass[String]] = init[SomeCaseClass[String]]()
```

It fails with

> ScalaFiddle.scala:16: error: type arguments [String] do not conform to method init's type parameter bounds [A <: ScalaFiddle.this.SomeCaseClass[_$1] forSome { type _$1 }]

You can check this [scalafiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/KuXZc0h/2).

**I do not know if this is the best approach**, but `init[A <: SomeCaseClass[_]]` is adding a type bound to `A`, and forcing `A` to be a Subclass of `SomeCaseClass`. I would love to know if there is a better way though.

Answer (score 5):

You can force a type parameter to be equal to some type `B` by using an implicit parameter:

```
def foo[A](implicit e: A =:= B): …
```

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450949/type-equality-in-scala).

To add some more value to this answer. 
Following code shows how to use the implicit parameter `e: A =:= String` to convert an `A` to a `String`.

```
def bar(b: String): Unit = println(b)
def foo[A](a: A)(implicit e: A =:= String): Unit = {
  bar(e(a))
}

foo("hi")  //compiles

foo(5)     //error: Cannot prove that scala.this.Int =:= String.
```

## Answer to problem the OP has

This problem is much simpler: Make the method parametric only in the parameter `A` of `SomeCaseClass[A]`, instead of using the whole type `SomeCaseClass[A]` as a type parameter:

```
private[this] def init[A](): SomeTrait[SomeCaseClass[A]] = new
  SomeTrait[SomeCaseClass[A]] {
    def get(oldId: String): SomeCaseClass[A] = ???
  }
```

Comment: Din't knew of `=:=`. To be precise with the OP, this is the closest solution, I think.

Comment: Could you provide a snippet showing how exactly this can be applied to my case?

Comment: @d-_-b Your problem might be much simpler. Please see my edit.

Comment: @ziggystar With this modification, it still compiles. i.e. `init[Int]()` or `init[String]()` throws no compilation errors. Am I missing something?

Comment: @d-_-b Yes, now it compiles with every type as argument. But given whatever type `A`, you will use only `SomeCaseClass[A]` internally. Isn't this what you want to achieve: `val aaa: SomeTrait[SomeCaseClass[String]] = init[String]()` This means that you cannot write the unwanted code; which is even better than making the unwanted code fail at compilation.

Answer (score 3):

This is based on the answer above:

```
case class SomeCaseClass[M] private (
  value: String
) 

trait SomeTrait[A] {
  def get(oldId: String): SomeCaseClass[A]
}

private[this] def init[A](): SomeTrait[A] = new SomeTrait[A] {
  def get(oldId: String): SomeCaseClass[A] = ???
}

val aaa: SomeTrait[String] = init[String]()
```

(https://scalafiddle.io/sf/KuXZc0h/3)

This doesn't allow other types than `SomeCaseClass` to be used with `SomeTrait`.