# How to enforce types for a graph between nodes

Tags: scala

I am trying to enforce a type relationship in a graph between a node and its parent.
I have the following that does not compile on child.parents ::= this.
Any comment would be welcomed

```
  trait TGraphNode {
    type NodeType <: TGraphNode
    var id = -1
    var parents = List[NodeType]()
    var children = List[TGraphNode]()

    def addChild(child: NodeType) {
      children ::= child
      child.parents ::= this
    }

    override def toString = "node-"+id+"->"+children
  }
```

Sorry - will add the compilation error next time. I am trying to achieve the following: imagine I have 2 nodes of type F and C - I want to enforce that C by construction can only have F as parent, however, the other way around I do not care. F could have C, D.. as children. So I want to capture that the ParentType can be overridden in a class implementing the trait.

```
class F extends TGraphNode ...
class B extends TGraphNode {
  type ParentType = F
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is

```
error: Type mismatch 
 found   : TGraphNode.this.type (with underlying type TGraphNode)
 required: child.NodeType
             child.parents ::= this
```

(please do not ommit that in your questions)

Your code states that a node may select the type it requires for its parents, with type variable `NodeType`. This type must conform to TGraphNode, but it may be much more restricted than that.

Given that, it is possible that the `child` added in `addChild` requires a type more restricted than `this` as its parent. It is proper that the compiler rejects that.

This is what the error message says : 
You put `this` in the parents list of child. `this` has type `TGraphNode`.
But the `parents` list is a list of the `NodeType` of the child (`child.NodeType`)
There is no guarantee than the type match.

I cannot comment further if you don't explain what you are trying to achieve.

---

After your edit :

You have to state that you will accept in addChild only a child that would accept this as a parent. It may be a little tricky, here is a possible way :

```
def addChild[N](child: TGraphNode{type NodeType = N})
               (implicit thisAsParentOfChild : this.type <:< N) {
  children ::= child
  child.parents ::= thisAsParentOfChild(this)
}
```

Having done that, you may now do

```
class F extends TGraphNode {type NodeType = TGraphNode }
class C extends TGraphNode {type NodeType = F }
class X extends TGraphNode {type NodeType = TGraphNode } 

val f = new F
val c = new C
val x = new X

f.addChild(c) // ok 
x.addChild(f) // ok

x.addChild(c) // error: Cannot prove that x.type <:< F
```

If you don't know what the implicit parameter with type <:< does, have a look at [What do <:<, <%<, and =:= mean in Scala 2.8, and where are they documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3427345/754787)

---

On second thought and reading bluenote suggestion, writing `addParent` is way simpler than `addChild` in your context (I believe this is the proper way to reverse chidren and parents) :

```
def addParent(parent: NodeType) {
  parents ::= parent
  parent.children ::= this
}
```

Comment: +1 for finding a solution that does not rely on inverting the construction order. Now the OP has both possibilities :).

Comment: Thx guys - I'll give it a shot tomorrow and will get back to you. Thanks for pointing at the <:<, <%<, etc. Resources on this are rare!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is, you just confused the types `NodeType` and `TGraphNode`. If I understood you correctly, the children could be of a subtype of `TGraphNode`. At least this is what the `addChild` function signature indicates and is maybe the more likely use case. So, the children must be of type `NodeType` but the parents can have the more general `TGraphNode` type, i.e.:

```
trait TGraphNode {
  type NodeType <: TGraphNode
  var id = -1
  var children = List[NodeType]()
  var parents = List[TGraphNode]()

  def addChild(child: NodeType) {
    children ::= child
    child.parents ::= this
  }

  override def toString = "node-"+id+"->"+children
}
```

**Edit:**

Ok, you really want it the other way around. Since the above mentioned version compiles, you could just reverse the definitions of children and parents to get what you want.