# Scala Generics Type Constraints

Tags: scala, generics, type-constraints

I am reading [Programming Scala](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0981531644) right now. I just got through the chapter on implicit type conversion, where the `<%` symbol is introduced. There is also a `<:` symbol and a `<` symbol.

Could someone please summarize the different type constraints? I am struggling with the difference between `<:` and `<` for instance. I am curious if there are any others I haven't covered yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds see also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427345/what-do-and-mean-in-scala-2-8-and-where-are-they-documented

Comment: @om-nom-nom I am not concerned with the operators addressed in the post you listed. I concerned the type constraint operators: `<:`, `<%`, `>:`, etc. They are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 17):

There is no type constraint called `<`.

`A <: B` means `A` is literally a subtype of `B` (where subtype is defined reflexively, meaning for any type `T` it is the case that `T <: T`).

`A <% B` means `A` is either a subtype of `B` or there is an implicit conversion from `A` to a distinct type `AA` for which `AA <: B`. This is called a "view bound."

`A >: B` means `A` is supertype of `B`.

Comment: You're right, there is no `<` constraint. What about the `>:` constraint?

Comment: I just started reading the chapter on implementing `List`. It explains that `>:` can be used to created a `List[Fruit]` when adding an `Orange` to a `List[Apple]`. It's a very interesting constraint.

Comment: More precisely:

A <% B means there is an implicit conversion from A to a distinct type AA for which AA <: B.

If A is a subtype of B, AA may be the same as A: The identity function (which is defined in Predef and always in scope) can be applied instead of an actual conversion.

But even if A is a subtype of B, there may be an implicit conversion to a different type AA that takes precedence over Predef.identity(). In that case, the compiler would infer type AA. Depends on precendence of implicits.