# Play source file "Reads.scala" use of generalized type constraint

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

In the Play framework source file, there is the following method inside the trait Reads[A]:

```
def andThen[B](rb: Reads[B])(implicit witness: A <:< JsValue): Reads[B] =
    rb.compose(this.map(witness))
```

and a map method like this:

```
def map[B](f: A => B): Reads[B] =
    Reads[B] { json => self.reads(json).map(f) }
```

witness is of type A <:< JsValue (which is a generalized type constraint). So how come it's being passed into the map method as an argument when the map method's parameter takes a function f: A => B??

Could someone explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because this type witness is also a function. It is declared in [`Predef`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L433) as:

```
sealed abstract class <:<[-From, +To] extends (From => To) with Serializable
```

So `A <:< JsValue` is also a function `(A) => JsValue`. You might wonder what the function does: it does nothing, it takes an `A` and directly returns it (as a `JsValue`).

To see why this is useful consider this example:

```
sealed trait Root { def bip() { println("bip") } }

def makeBip[A <: Root](a: A) {
  a.bip() // works because a is known to the type system to be a Root
}

def makeBip2[A](a: A)(implicit ev: A <:< Root) {
  a.bip() // works, because implicit resolution turns it into `ev(a).bip()`
}
```

The last method `makeBip2` would not compile without the implicit because even though *you* know that `a` is a `Root` thanks to the evidence, the type system doesn't. You could cast it, it would be sure to work:

```
def makeBip3[A](a: A)(implicit ev: A <:< Root) {
  a.asInstanceOf[Root].bip() // ugly
}
```

But this doesn't feel right. If only you had a way you convert `a` to a `Root`... but wait, you do: the evidence itself!

```
def makeBip4[A](a: A)(implicit ev: A <:< Root) {
  ev(a).bip() // works!
}
```

And since implicit parameters are available as implicits within the method, `a.bip()` will be automatically converted to `ev(a).bip()` and you never need to know a function was involved.

However, the type system only uses the implicit to resolve an `A` into a `JsValue`, but not a `Seq[A]` into a `Seq[JsValue]` or a `Reads[A]` into a `Reads[JsValue]`.

So in you case, `this.map(witness)` just makes the type system understand that a `Reads[A]` is a `Reads[JsValue]` by applying that function that does nothing, so that it can be composed with something that takes a `JsValue` and returns a `B`.

See the [Generalized type constraits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427345/what-do-and-mean-in-scala-2-8-and-where-are-they-documented) question on SO for more.