# Conditional methods of Scala generic classes with restrictions for type parameters

Tags: scala, generics

I believe that a generic class may make one of its methods available only assuming that its type parameters conform to some additional restrictions, something like (syntax improvised on the spot):

```
trait Col[T] extends Traversable[T] {
    def sum[T<:Int] :T = (0/:this)(_+_)
}
```

I guess I could use implicit parameters as evidence... Is there a language feature for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you can only use an implicit parameter, as the type gets determined before the method call.

```
trait Col[T] extends Traversable[T] {
  def sum(implicit num: Numeric[T]) :T = ???
}
```

If the method you are calling would be parameterized, you could use context bounds, which are just syntactic sugar for the implicit parameter bound to the type parameter:

```
def foo[A](implicit ev: Something[A]) = ???
```

is equivalent to

```
def foo[A : Something] = ???
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that [T :Evidence] is a general notation, I used it only with TypeTags. How do I access the actual implicit parameter from a method written this way?  Also, won't declaration `def sum[T :Numeric]` overshadow trait type parameter T?

Comment: Usually you use this notation, when you use other methods that expect a parameter of that kind in the body, but you can also get it by calling `implicitly[Something[A]]`. For some types there may even be getters, like for `ClassTag` there is `scala.reflect.classTag[A]` that implicitly takes the `ClassTag` instance and just returns it. You can also just create your own methods or apply methods of this kind on the companions of the type you implicitly pass in.

Comment: Thx, I'll play with it.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use a *type bound* on the type parameter, which is enforced by an implicit argument:

```
trait Col[T] extends Traversable[T] {
    def sum(implicit ev: T <:< Int) :T = (0/:this)(_+_)
}
```

`<:<` is actually a class, expressed in infix notation, defined in [Predef.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L1) and explained in many places, including [here](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html)

`<:<` means 'must be a subtype of'

You can also use `=:=` 'must be equal to' and `X <%< Y` 'must be viewable as' (ie. there is an implicit conversion to X from Y)

For a more detailed explanation of type constraints, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427345/what-do-and-mean-in-scala-2-8-and-where-are-they-documented).

Answer (score 1):

there is another option involving implicit classes conversions

```
trait Col[T] extends Traversable[T] 

implicit class ColInt[T <: Int](val v : Col[T]) extends AnyVal {
    def sum : T = (0 /: v)(_ + _)
}
```

in this context you don't need the empty trait Col anymore, so you could further comprimize it to this:

```
implicit class ColInt[T <: Int](val v : Traversable[T]) extends AnyVal {
    def sum : T = (0 /: v)(_ + _)
}
```

The advantage of this method is, that it tells the compiler, that type T is really a subtype of Int, so `List[T] <: List[Int]` is still valid in this context, and no explicit conversion needs to be added. The implicit parameter adds implicit conversions that wouldn't work on `List[T]`, because it only introduces an implicit conversion from `T` to `Int`, not from `List[T]` to `List[Int]`