# Deferred type inference on method call

Tags: scala, type-inference, implicit

I was reading the (great) post [A Generic Quicksort in Scala](http://suereth.blogspot.hu/2011/06/generic-quicksort-in-scala.html) from Josh Suereth. Especially interesting was the part about the deferring of type inference for collections.

Now I wonder if this also applies for non-collections. The following 2 methods create a `Foo[T,O]`

```
def sort1[T, O](from: T, to: T)(implicit ev: O <:< Ordering[T], ord: O):Foo[T,O] = {
   ...
}

def sort2[T, O <: Ordering[Int]](from: T, to: T)(implicit ord: O):Foo[T,O] = {
   ...
}
```

Which of the two methods is preferred and why?

`sort2(2,5)` does work, with `sort1(2,5)` the compiler seems find more implicits since there is an ambiguous implicit resolution error.

Comment: Other link http://jsuereth.com/scala/2011/06/16/generic-quicksort.html

Comment: I think the answer is "neither": use `def sort[T](from: T, to: T)(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Foo[T, Ordering[T]] = ...` (see also *context bounds* if you don't need to use `ord` directly)

Comment: @LuigiPlinge I thought about it. But for me it is important which Ordering was used to create the Foo. For example a function `compose(foo1, foo2)` should only accept `Foo` with sorted with the same `Ordering`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deferring type inference using [generalized type constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427345/what-do-and-mean-in-scala-2-8-and-where-are-they-documented) is all about going around limitations with type inference. These limitations are not necessarily bugs, they can be by design.

I can think of two common situations where they are useful:

- You want to get the type inside another higher-kinded type, but you have no constraint to get it.

  Example:

  ```
  def sort[T, Coll <: SeqLike[T, Coll](a: Coll): Coll
  ```

  The compiler has no way to get the type parameter `T` because it is not constraint in any way: it does not appear on the left-hand side of a `<:` or `>:` in the type parameter list, and does not appear in the argument's types.

  Generalized type constraints allow here to constraint (through an argument) the type `T`:

  ```
  def sort[T, Coll](a: Coll)(implicit ev: Coll <:< SeqLike[T, Coll]): Coll
  ```

  *Note*: this is only one way to do this. There is usually a way to get <strike>the same thing</strike> *something very close* without the implicit evidence. Here it would be:

  ```
  def sort[T, Coll <: SeqLike[T, Coll]](a: Coll with SeqLike[T, Coll]): Coll
  ```
- You have no control over the type parameter, because it comes from the enclosing class.

  For example, adding a `flatten` method on `List[A]` that only works if `A` is a collection itself. You cannot change the type parameter `A` just for that one method, but you can locally add a constraint with an `implicit ev: A <:< Traversable[B]` or something similar.

  *Note 2*: this isn't what is done in the collection library, which uses `implicit ev: (A) => Traversable[B]`, so that anything that can be converted to a collection works (like `String` or `Array`), but sometimes you do not want that.

**Edit** to address the `sort1` vs `sort2` question: adding a generalized type constraint when none is needed can create this kind of error because types become under-constrained. Since there is no constraint on `O` in `sort1`, `ord: O` can be anything. The implicit evidence can only be used to view an `O` as an `Ordering[T]` within the body of the method.

If you really wanted to keep the implicit evidence, you would have to re-introduce some constraint somewhere. On the type parameter like in `sort2`, or on `ord` itself:

```
def sort3[T, O](from: T, to: T)
  (implicit ev: O <:< Ordering[T], ord: O with Ordering[T]):Foo[T,O]
```

in this case, `sort2` seems to be the best way to do this.

Comment: The blog mentions to avoid specifying the number of type params. I just noticed this with TraversableLike.to. You can to[List] but never to[Map]. Use case was Map.mapValues.toMap returns itself; I was going for a different idiom from .view.force or .iterator.toMap.

Comment: @som-snytt sadly one can avoid specifying the number of type params when asking for a type, but not for a type constructor. I would kill for a `def to[Coll[_*]] = macro to_Impl` that pattern matches on the number of type params (including 0) and looks for the proper implicits...

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, this can seems unintuitive.

The reason is that sort1 defines no constraints on O, so 'ord: O' is ambiguous.
(the constraint on the first implicit parameter only defines a constraint on 'ev' type).

Hope it helps :)