# Passing a class type as a parameter in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to parse a Json Object. I have defined the following class:

```
case class Metadata(
  val messageTime:   Option[String], 
  val messageUUID:   Option[String], 
  val messageSource: Option[String], 
  val messageFormat: Option[String])
```

I generate a dummy object of this type:

```
jsonMsg = """{"messageTime": "2018-09-19T11:03:22.382+04:00", 
 "messageUUID": "4ef7fce7-81cf-4a27-82d8-9019c2cf09df", 
 "messageSource" : "SDG", 
 "messageFormat" : "json"}"""
```

Now I want to use `mapper.readValue` to parse that string into an Object of type Metadata:

```
fromJson(jsonMsg) 

def fromJson(json : String)  = {
mapper.readValue[Metadata](json, classOf[Metadata])
}
```

This works fine. But in this case fromJson can only parse Metadata objects.

Now I tried to make my method fromJson more generic, passing the class of the object to be parsed like this [I used this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28112891/1773841) as a reference ]:

```
val obj = fromJson2(jsonMsg, classOf[Metadata])

def fromJson2(json : String, c: Class[_])  = {
  mapper.readValue(json, c)
}
```

But I get the error:

> forward reference extends over definition of value obj

What am I missing or how could I achieve what I am trying?

**Just in case**
`mapper.readValue` belongs to `import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`

And this is the definition:

```
public <T> T readValue(String content, Class<T> valueType)
    throws IOException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException
{
    return (T) _readMapAndClose(_jsonFactory.createParser(content), _typeFactory.constructType(valueType));
}
```

Comment: What is the `obj` that the error message complains about? Show more complete code.

Comment: @Thilo it is the ouput of the call to fromJson2. I will edit

Comment: Is that really `Val` with a capital `V` ? Does moving the definition of `fromJson2` ahead of its use help (that is usually what "forward reference" talks about)?

Comment: @Thilo it was that... didnt expect the order matters in scala. Such a long question for such a silly mistake. Thanks a lot Thilo!