# Enforcing polymorphic parameters to be of same type

Tags: scala, polymorphism

In the method below, I was hoping to set up the type of the function to 
enforce that `from` and `to` are the same type of LexicalDate. I.e. they must both be `Day` or both must be `Hour`.

Currently, `from` and `to` can be passed as different types of LexicalDate.

Can `from` and `to` be forced at the compile level to always be the same type of `LexicalDate`?

```
sealed trait LexicalDate 
case object Day extends LexicalDate
case object Hour extends LexicalDate
def queryDate[Date <: LexicalDate](
    id: Long,
    from: Date,
    to: Date
  )
```

Comment: I can't see any reason to do this. The only time you'd ever need this was if the implementations broke the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/liskov-s-substitution-principle.html) (I think) and behaved wildly differently from one another. Interesting thought though.

Comment: What's your question? (BTW, your declaration of `Hour` should be `case object Hour extends LexicalDate` not just `case object Hour extends`. Was that your problem?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the generalized type constraint `=:=`, which requires that a compiler should be able to prove that two types are equal. For your case, `=:=` can be used as follows (in particular, note the implicit parameter list of the `queryDate` method):

```scala
scala> def queryDate[A <: LexicalDate, B <: LexicalDate](id: Long, from: A, to: B)(implicit ev: A =:= B) { }
queryDate: [A <: LexicalDate, B <: LexicalDate](id: Long, from: A, to: B)(implicit ev: A =:= B)Unit

scala> queryDate(10, Day, Day)

scala> queryDate(10, Hour, Hour)

scala> queryDate(10, Day, Hour)
<console>:15: error: Cannot prove that Day.type =:= Hour.type.
       queryDate(10, Day, Hour)
                ^

scala> queryDate(10, Hour, Day)
<console>:15: error: Cannot prove that Hour.type =:= Day.type.
       queryDate(10, Hour, Day)
                ^
```

Refer to the following links for the general description of generalized type constraints:

- [What do <:<, <%<, and =:= mean in Scala 2.8, and where are they documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3427759/234658)
- [Generalized type constraints in Scala (without a PhD)](http://blog.bruchez.name/2015/11/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala.html)

Comment: This works out great! The one downside to this is if you wanted to call something that called queryDate, it seems that this type check only works when you call it directly.