# How to define a scala method with type param that cannot be Any

Tags: scala, types, type-constraints

In below example, I want to define a `contains` method that doesn't compile if `a` and `b` are not of the same base type.

- In `contains1` impl, if `a` is `Seq[Int]` and b is `String`, `T` is derived to be `Any`, and it compiles. This is not I want.
- In `contains2` impl, if `a` is `Seq[Int]` and b is `String`, then it doesn't compile. The behavior is what I want.

```scala
def contains1[T](a: Seq[T], b: T): Boolean = a.contains(b)

println(contains1(Seq(1,2,3), "four")) // false

def contains2[T: Ordering](a: Seq[T], b: T): Boolean = a.contains(b)

println(contains2(Seq(1,2,3), "four")) // compilation error
// cmd7.sc:1: No implicit Ordering defined for Any.
// val res7 = isMatched(Seq(1,2,3), "s")
                    ^
// Compilation Failed
```

However, is there a simpler way to achieve the same behaviour as in `contains2`? `Ordering` context bound confuses me as the method has nothing to do with sorting/ordering at all.

Comment: Type inference works using the unification algorithm, and it work really hard to ensure things compile... sometimes, harder than one would want, like this case. One workaround is to define it like this: `def contains[T](a: Seq[T])(b: T): Boolean = a.contains(b)`. In this case, since **b** is in a separate argument list, it is not take into account when inferring the type parameter **T**, in really the already inferred type **T** is used, as such, if `b` is not of the same _type_ as the elements in the collection, it will not compile. - Additionally, one advice, add the `-Xlint:infer-any` flag.

Comment: As @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez says, splitting up the arguments is probably the simplest fix. As an alternative, though, you could do something like `def contains2[T: Eq](a: Seq[T], b: T): Boolean = a.exists(Eq[T].eqv(b, _))` with Cats's `Eq`, where the constraint is both meaningful and actually used in the operation. (Unfortunately `Any` has a `scala.math.Equiv` instance, so that's not really useful here.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use **generalized type constraints** operator `=:=`.

For example:

```
def contains[A,B](a: Seq[A], b: B)(implicit evidence: A =:= B): Boolean = a.contains(b)
```

and then:

```
println(contains1(Seq(1,2,3), "four")) //fails with Cannot prove that Int =:= String.
println(contains1(Seq("one"), "four")) //returns false
println(contains1(Seq("one", "four"), "four")) //true
```

More on generalized type constraints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427345/what-do-and-mean-in-scala-2-8-and-where-are-they-documented) and [here](https://apiumhub.com/tech-blog-barcelona/scala-generics-generalized-type-constraints/).

As LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez noticed, you could also consider using `B <:< A` instead of `A =:= B`. I won't elaborate on differences between these two because it's described in linked answer and article, but in brief, `<:<` would also allow all `B` that are a subtype of `A`, while `=:=` needs types to match exactly.

Comment: If going the **Generalized Type Constraints** way, I would use `implicit ev: B <:< A` which would give more flexibility, while maintaining _type safety_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Sure. I edited my answer. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: _"all A that are a subtype of B"_, in this case that would not make much sense, since `A` is the type parameter of the collection. It would make more sense as _"all `B` that are a subtype of `A`"_, but then you would need to flip the arguments, as I did in my comment ;)

Comment: I guess it would make the most sense if you could do something like `A <:< B || B <:< A`, because then you could do `contains(Seq(Seq("one")), List("four"))` and `contains(Seq(List("one")), Seq("four"))`,  but I think I can't be done :)

Comment: I do not know if it can be done, but I do not think it would make more sense. `A <:< B` means `A` could be a subtype of `B`, in this case that means that a collection of a "inferior" type _(in the sense of a scale of concreteness)_ could contain any "superior" value... that could lead to a: Collection of **Ints** could contain a **String**, since `B` could be inferred as **Any**... which is the original problem. On the other hand, `B <:< A` would only mean that a collection of **Pets** can contain a **Dog** _(which by the definition of the Liskov principle, must be true)_.