# Two implicit definitions with same name for a method

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

I have two implicit declarations that "redefine" x as an operator:

```
import scala.io.StdIn._
import util._
import scala.language.postfixOps


case class Rectangle(width: Int, height: Int)
case class Circle(ratio: Integer)
case class Cylinder[T](ratio: T, height: T)


object implicitsExample1 {

    implicit class RectangleMaker(width: Int) {
        def x(height: Int) = Rectangle(width, height)
    }

    implicit class CircleMaker(ratio: Int) {
        def c = Circle(ratio)
    }

    implicit class CylinderMaker[T](ratio: T) {
        def x(height: T) = Cylinder(ratio, height)
    }


    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        val myRectangle = 3 x 4
        val myCircle = 3 c
        val myCylinder = 4 x 5

        println("myRectangle = " + myRectangle)

        println("myCircle = " + myCircle) 

        println("myCylinder = " + myCylinder)

    }

}
```

Here my output gives:

```
myRectangle = Rectangle(3,4)
myCircle = Circle(3)
myCylinder = Rectangle(4,5)
```

What I need to do to have something like:

```
myCylinder = Cylinder[Int](4,5)
```

I understand that the chosen implicit conversion is the first one declared but is there a way to specify the use of the `Cylinder` one?

Comment: The chosen implicit conversion is not the first one declared, but the one that has the most specific parameter types. At least you could do `new CylinderMaker(4) x 5`, but it's not a pretty solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try combining `RectangleMaker` and `CylinderMaker` into a single `ShapeMaker` implicit class like so

```
implicit class ShapeMaker[T](width: T) {
  def x(height: T)(implicit ev: T =:= Int) = Rectangle(width, height)
  def x(height: T) = Cylinder[T](width, height)
}
```

and provide type ascriptions to value definitions like so

```
val myRectangle: Rectangle = 3 x 4
val myCircle = 3 c
val myCylinder: Cylinder[Int] = 4 x 5
```

which outputs

```
myRectangle = Rectangle(3,4)
myCircle = Circle(3)
myCylinder = Cylinder(4,5)
```

Comment: is the meaning of:   implicit ev: T =:= Int  
"ev is a variable with type Int"?

Comment: Yes, it is called a [generalised type constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56637500/5205022).