# Generalized constraints within type parameter clause?

Tags: scala, type-parameter, type-constraints, kind-projector

SLS specifies syntax of [type parameter clause](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/13-syntax-summary.html) as

```
TypeParamClause   ::=  ‘[’ VariantTypeParam {‘,’ VariantTypeParam} ‘]’
FunTypeParamClause::=  ‘[’ TypeParam {‘,’ TypeParam} ‘]’
VariantTypeParam  ::=  {Annotation} [‘+’ | ‘-’] TypeParam
TypeParam         ::=  (id | ‘_’) [TypeParamClause] [‘>:’ Type] [‘<:’ Type] {‘<%’ Type} {‘:’ Type}                  {‘<%’ Type} {‘<%’ Type}
```

where we see  `>:`, `<:`, `<%`, `<%`, `:` as allowed reserved names in type parameter clause. Is there a way we could use [generalised type constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56637500/5205022) symbolic names `<:<`, `=:=` in the type parameter clause such that

```
def f[T =:= 42] = ???
```

would expand to

```
def f[T](implicit ev: T =:= 42) = ???
```

similar to how context bound

```
def f[T: Numeric] = ???
```

expands to

```
def f[T](implicit ev: Numeric[T]) = ???
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 2.13 (which supports singleton types if you are curious about constraining on singletons) you can do things like:

```
@ import $plugin.$ivy.`org.typelevel:kind-projector_2.13.1:0.11.0`
import $plugin.

@ type a = 23
defined type a

@ def f[N : * =:= a]: Unit = ()
defined function f

@ f[a]


@ f[23]


@ f[25]
cmd9.sc:1: Cannot prove that 25 =:= Int(23).
val res9 = f[25]
            ^
Compilation Failed

@ def g[N : * =:= 16]: Unit = ()
defined function g

@ g[16]


@ g[23]
cmd11.sc:1: Cannot prove that 23 =:= 16.
val res11 = g[23]
             ^
Compilation Failed
```

So, yes, it seems possible. You just have to use kind projectors to apply second parameter.

With `<:<` it should be the same story:

```
@ def h[N : * <:< 16]: Unit = ()
defined function h

@ h[16]


@ h[17]
cmd13.sc:1: Cannot prove that 17 <:< 16.
val res13 = h[17]
             ^
Compilation Failed
```