# Why does ScalaTest by default not enforce types when matching?

Tags: scala, scalatest, specs2

I was wondering why ScalaTest behaves differently compared to Specs2.

**Specs2**

```scala
"" must be equalTo 3
```

```
TestSpec.scala:11:26: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Int(3)
[error]  required: String
[error]       "" must be equalTo 3
```

**ScalaTest**

```scala
3 should === ("r")
```

```
[info] Done compiling.
[info] TestTest:
[info] Dummy test
[info] - should fail *** FAILED ***
[info]   "" did not equal 3 (PersistentTaskRuntimeTest.scala:21)
```

ScalaTest by default only fails at runtime, everything is compared as Any-to-Any.

There is the Supersafe plugin to get better checks (or `TypeCheckedTripleEquals`) but these feel like hacks as Specs2 just uses the scala compiler to require the types of the two values compared to be in a subtype/supertype relationship.

For reference this is the output when using `TypeCheckedTripleEquals`, mind the hacky `CanEqual`

```
TestTest.scala:21:7: types String and Int do not adhere to the type constraint selected for the === and !== operators; the missing implicit parameter is of type org.scalactic.CanEqual[String,Int]
[error]     "" should === (3)
[error]       ^
```

So what is the rationale behind this?

- Less heavy for the scala compiler?
- Less code to write for ScalaTest?
- Less implicit magic (cryptic error messages)?
- Pushing a commercial compiler plugin?

Answer (score 1):

[`TypeCheckedTripleEquals`](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/57151f83937a4adb23d402efecfe76d4c96c73ac/scalactic/src/main/scala/org/scalactic/TypeCheckedTripleEquals.scala#L305) is using [generalised type constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427345/what-do-and-mean-in-scala-2-8-and-where-are-they-documented), for example, `B <:< A` in

```
implicit override def typeCheckedConstraint[A, B](implicit equivalenceOfA: Equivalence[A], ev: B <:< A): A CanEqual B
```

This is standard Scala functionality to enforce compile-time safety, and is used in many widespread Scala libraries. For example,

```
import org.scalactic.TypeCheckedTripleEquals
import org.scalatest._

class CompileTimeSafetySpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with TypeCheckedTripleEquals {
  "TypeCheckedTripleEquals" should "provide compile-time safety" in {
    3 should === ("r")
  }
}
```

gives compiler error

```
types Int and String do not adhere to the type constraint selected for the === and !== operators; the missing implicit parameter is of type org.scalactic.CanEqual[Int,String]
[error]     3 should === ("r")
```