# Implement Java interface in Scala, with generics, and return null

Tags: java, scala

I have a Java interface that looks roughly like this:

```
public interface Foo {
  public <T> T bar();
}
```

I want to implement this interface in Scala, where all of my code uses `Option`. However, since the interface will be used by Java users, I want to return `null` instead of `None`. I tried the following:

```
class FooImpl extends Foo {
  def bar[T](): T = {
    val barOpt: Option[T] = getBar()
    barOpt.orNull
  }
}
```

This results in the following compile error:

```
Expression of type Null does not conform to expected type T
```

This makes sense, type `T` is unrestricted, it could be an `Int` or some other type that can't be `null`. No problem, just add `T >: Null` and you're done, right?

```
class FooImpl extends Foo {
  def bar[T >: Null](): T = {
    val barOpt: Option[T] = getBar()
    barOpt.orNull
  }
}
```

Nope, still no dice. Now you get a new compile error:

```
[error]  method bar has incompatible type
```

It seems that you can't apply any restrictions to `T` and still implement that interface.

Next, I tried using `asInstanceOf`:

```
class FooImpl extends Foo {
  def bar[](): T = {
    val barOpt: Option[T] = getBar()
    barOpt.orNull.asInstanceOf[T]
  }
}
```

But that just gets one more error:

```
Cannot prove that Null <:< T.
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: [try here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065962/how-to-return-null-from-a-generic-function-in-scala)

Comment: @BevynQ: As I wrote in the description, the first thing I tried was `T >: Null`, but that leads to the second error.

Comment: I don't know scala, but does it support this kind of construct? `barOpt.<T>orNull`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use getOrElse and cast to `T`:

```
scala> def test[T](t: T): T = { Option(t).getOrElse(null).asInstanceOf[T] }
test: [T](t: T)T
```

You could move ugly stuff to helper class:

```
implicit class Defaults[T](val o: Option[T]) extends AnyVal {
  def orDefault(): T = o.getOrElse(null).asInstanceOf[T]
}

def test[T](t: T): T = { Option(t).orDefault }
```

Comment: I know, but `T` could be `AnyVal`. You could hide casting see update.

Answer (score 2):

Just an fyi, if you are using play, the same helper already exists in the libs package: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/libs/Scala.java#L12

Answer (score 0):

I suspect @senia's answer will prove to be the best option available in pure Scala. If nothing new comes in, I'll mark it as the "official" answer.

For completeness, here is a workaround using a Java class to encapsulate this dirty business, give it a clear name, and, just as importantly, document why it exists:

```
public class JavaOptionHelper {
  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205142/implement-java-interface-in-scala-with-generics-and-return-null
  public static <T> T toValueOrNull(Option<T> option) {
    if (option.isDefined()) {
      return option.get();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

It can be used as follows:

```
class FooImpl extends Foo {
  def bar[T](): T = {
    val barOpt: Option[T] = getBar()
    JavaOptionHelper.toValueOrNull(barOpt)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
scala> def test[T >: Null] = null
test: [T >: Null]=> Null

scala> test[String]
res18: Null = null

scala> def test2[T](x : T)(implicit ev: Null <:< T) = x
test2: [T](x: T)(implicit ev: <:<[Null,T])T

scala> test2("Hallo")
res19: java.lang.String = Hallo

scala> test2(null)
res20: Null = null
```

There is even a discussion on StackOverflow which covers the topic quite good. For details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440134/is-this-the-proper-way-to-initialize-null-references-in-scala).